# How to convert commandline curl to php Curl

Tags: php, curl

Hi I am newbie for php and curl.I want to convert following command line curl php curl.I have searched and got some options on following link.
http://www.whatsmyip.org/lib/php-curl-option-guide/

But i have a problem on converting the metdata part .

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
-F 'metadata={"description":"YaRetail Taxonomy"}' \
-F 'data=@yahooTaxonomy.json;type=application/json' \
datax.yahooapis.com/v1/taxonomy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, example:

```
$multipartData = array(
    'metadata={"description":"YaRetail Taxonomy"}',
    'data=@yahooTaxonomy.json;type=application/json'
);

$headers = array("Content-Type: multipart/form-data");

$ch = curl_init('http://random.url');
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($multipartData));
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

NOTE: I did not test the code so you should check it first.